# I’m going to make sure the federal government does [what's needed to be done] in Kentucky

Tags: passive-voice

This is the first sentence from [President Biden's tweet](https://twitter.com/POTUS/status/1471208691839950855):

> I’m going to make sure the federal government does **what’s needed to be done** in Kentucky.

By the emboldened phrase, I think he means "what needs to be done". Is it a mere typo or is there more to using "is needed" instead of "needs"?

FYI, I've looked at [an earlier thread](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/18799/118290) saying that "what is needed to be done" could work, but I don't think such a reading would work in the current tweet, because such a reading would force the sentence to mean "I’m going to make sure the federal government does what’s needed for the federal government to be done in Kentucky," which I think is nonsensical.

Comment: "what *is needed* [by the people] to be done [by the government]" -> passive + passive infinitive; "what *needs* to be done [by the government]" -> active + passive infinitive. -- Both are good.

Comment: So is "make sure the federal government does what's needed in Kentucky." I would not have thought of Twitter as a hospitable platform for pleonasm, but there it is.

Comment: @Greybeard If both are good, how come [this Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is+needed+to+be+done%2Cneeds+to+be+done&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cis%20needed%20to%20be%20done%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cneeds%20to%20be%20done%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cis%20needed%20to%20be%20done%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cneeds%20to%20be%20done%3B%2Cc0) says otherwise?

Comment: @BrianDonovan I don't think it's pleonasm, because _what's needed_ is clearly different from _what needs to be done_.

Comment: @listeneva 1. The Ngram shows the frequency not the "correctness". 2. Just because something is infrequent, does not mean that it is wrong.

Comment: @Greybeard Like I have said in the OP, I'm not saying that _what’s needed to be done_ is impossible English. It can be used in rare contexts as shown in the earlier thread I've cited. But I don't believe your analysis of the construction to fit in with the OP's context.

Comment: I agree with the OP about what Biden intended. This is a type of minor grammatical error that many people make in extemporaneous speech.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks! That's what I have suspected. It's one thing to make a minor error (every human being including the POTUS does), but isn't it entirely a different thing not to recognize and/or acknowledge the error even after it's been pointed out? I mean, what's going on here? Is it because this "error" is somehow that hard to notice? Or is it because they didn't want to acknowledge that the President made such an error?